# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for if statement

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason, the if statement I'm using doesn't run within my for statement.

I tried the checkbox "replace by space" in the Settings > Preferences > Language Menu / Tab Settings but it still doesn't work.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('corrections.db')
c = conn.cursor()

for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Name= 'Tim'"):{
    if 1<2: 
       print{"hello")
}

conn.commit()
```

The error displays at the if statement, but if I move the if statement out of the for loop, it works perfectly.

Comment: In Python you don't need curly brackets to indicate scopes. Python relies solely on indentation levels (and usually opening a scope with `:` as you did at the end of the `if`)

Answer (score 2):

Context is everything; the `if` is a problem because of the `{` preceding it.

(You'll also need to change `print{` to `print(`.)